# How to get query parameters? Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to use a variable "?search=value" in my child component.

Root component config:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '...', name: 'Project', component: ProjectComponent, useAsDefault: true}
])
class App {}
```

Child component config:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'List', component: ProjectListComponent, useAsDefault: true }
])
export class ProjectComponent{
    constructor(
        private _routeParams: RouteParams
    ){
        console.log(this._routeParams.get('search'))
    }
```

I open

```
localhost:3000/?search=example
```

I see (itself changes)

```
http://localhost:3000/;search=example?search=example  // wtf???
```

and

```
console.log(this._routeParams.get('search')); // example
```

I open

```
http://localhost:3000/;search=example
```

I see

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

and

```
console.log(this._routeParams.get('search')); // null - wtf???
```

Please help =)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to corner case for the router. `...` is non-terminal route mark, it is the same as `/...`, `ProjectComponent` always loads during navigation since it matches every url. `ProjectListComponent` is mapped to `/` so it is effectively mapped to the same route as `ProjectComponent` but treated as child route due to inheritance - some kind of collision, both components are on the same url. Parameters start with `;` for child routers (matrix parameters) and question mark `?` is used for the main router parameters only.

Both child and parent routers capture parameters:

```
http://localhost:3000/?search=example
```

Main router expects `?` so it does not capture parameter:

```
http://localhost:3000/;search=example
```

Also `useAsDefault` adds its bits:

> If true, the child route will be navigated to if no child route is
>   specified during the navigation.

i bet navigation changes that you see are caused by this parameter. It is difficult to say how exactly it works without debugging.

Comment: I want render lists with help url of parameter, but when I open '/;search=bla' ProjectListComponent this._routeParams.get('search')) have 'null' =((

When I open '/?search=bla' I see '/;search=bla?search=bla' and this._routeParams.get('search')) have 'bla'

I want clean url with only '/?search=bla' without '/;search=bla?search=bla'

Comment: you should assign distinct paths for your components i.e. `/project/...` for `ProjectComponent` and `/list` for `ProjectListComponent` then you could use matrix parameters `/project/list/;search=bla`

Answer (score 2):

Angular-2 support **Query Parameters** but shown in different view in browser address bar. some time shown like as `/heroes?id=15&foo=foo` and some time shown as `/heroes;id=15;foo=foo`.

You should know when will show `/heroes?id=15&foo=foo` and when will show `/heroes;id=15;foo=foo`

`/heroes?id=15&foo=foo` will show in browser url when route is **parent** route

`/heroes;id=15;foo=foo` will show in browser url when route is **child** route

but from both both url can get `id` by using `routeParams.get()` like:

```
constructor(routeParams: RouteParams) {
  this._selectedId = +routeParams.get('id');
})
```

when URL **separated by semicolons (;)** that means this is matrix URL notation

> Matrix URL notation is an idea first floated in a 1996 proposal by the
>   founder of the web, Tim Berners-Lee.
>
> Although matrix notation never made it into the HTML standard, it is
>   legal and it became popular among browser routing systems as a way to
>   isolate parameters belonging to parent and child routes. The Angular
>   Component Router is such a system.
>
> The syntax may seem strange to us but users are unlikely to notice or
>   care as long as the URL can be emailed and pasted into a browser
>   address bar as this one can.

how identify parent and child route? for child route used `/...` for example say in your `app.component` file

```
@RouteConfig([

  { // Crisis Center child route
    path: '/crisis-center/...',
    name: 'CrisisCenter',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
  },
  // here heroes is parent/ route route
  {path: '/heroes',   name: 'Heroes',     component: HeroListComponent}
])
```

[See this example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html) got to *crisis center details* and click on **Cancel** and go to *heros details* and click on **Back** to show different url

**N.B:** plunker view pop out the preview window by clicking the blue 'X' button in the upper right corner.